# Is there a single word for "as it is"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that replaces the phrase "as it is". Only a single word should be used to convey the complete meaning.
Sample sentence:
Don't touch the phone. Leave it as it is.

"As it is" as used with the meaning " actual state of things".

Thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to follow the guidance for single-word requests.

Comment: I edited the question and now it contains a sample sentence.

Comment: Thank you. Reöpened. But there are a lot of possible one-word answers, none of which seem particularly unobvious nor especially helpful to future visitors, including *be* and *thus* and *there* and *so*.

Comment: In some contexts you could say *alone*. "Leave (the thing) alone".

Comment: @JimMack *Alone* works perfectly in the OP's example and yours.

Comment: "Leave it!" is effective and pithy on its own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Be**

as in

> Leave it *be*.

*Being* is the state of existing without a more interesting quality (such as changing). Leaving it to be is leaving it as it currently is.

Comment: Didn't The Beatles do a song called *Leave It Be*? (-:

Answer (score 0):

Stet. Found this as an answer to a trivia question.

Comment: It's a term used in marking up printing but not really used outside of that.

Comment: Stet is an instruction, it does not describe the current position.